# Android Widget not updating RemoteViewsService

Tags: android, widget

Widget onUpdate() is called but data in list view does not change

It loads correct data when widget is placed at screen first time only then
after 1hr widget onUpdate() is called but data inside is not updated

## AppWidget_4X3.java

```
public class AppWidget_4X3 extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, widget_Update_Service.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget_4_x3);
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.widget_list_view_4_x3, intent);
        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_list_view_4_x3, R.id.empty_view);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
}
```

## widget_Update_Service.java

```
public class widget_Update_Service extends RemoteViewsService {
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new ListRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}}

class ListRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
private List<WidgetItem> mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<WidgetItem>();
private Context mContext;
private int mAppWidgetId;
int no_of_col;
SharedPreferences sp_no_of_col;
String column_stored = "No_column_stored";
String table_file_name = "table_data";

public ListRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}

public void onCreate() {

    L.msg("onCreate widget_Update_Service");
    sp_no_of_col= mContext.getSharedPreferences(table_file_name, 0);
    no_of_col = sp_no_of_col.getInt(column_stored, 2);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_col; i++) {
        mWidgetItems.add(new WidgetItem(i,mContext,dayOfWeek-1));

    }

}

public void onDestroy() {

    try {
        mWidgetItems.clear();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return no_of_col;
}

public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_item_time_from, mWidgetItems.get(position).time_from);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_item_subject,mWidgetItems.get(position).subject);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_item_time_to, mWidgetItems.get(position).time_to);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);

        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item_time_to, fillInIntent);


    return rv;
}

public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {

    return null;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public void onDataSetChanged() {

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Adding  `appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.widget_list_view_4_x3);`** fixed update the problem

## AppWidget_4X3.java#

```
public class AppWidget_4X3 extends AppWidgetProvider {


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
super.onReceive(context, intent);}


public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {



        Intent intent = new Intent(context, widget_Update_Service.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget_4_x3);
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.widget_list_view_4_x3, intent);


        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_list_view_4_x3, R.id.empty_view);


 appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.widget_list_view_4_x3);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);

    }

super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```